# Any solution abour Flutter Error: Error Opening Emulator?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

Flutter was working perfectly, but suddenly had this error. I tried many solutions, but none of them worked, thanks for any help!

```
INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath /Users/basem/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86/ 
INFO | Found systemPath /Users/basem/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86/ 
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan 
ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. 
ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. 
INFO | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-basem/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled 
INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you tried flutter doctor?

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing says the problem you're having is with Vulkan. [Vulkan](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics) is a Graphics Api. Google announced a few months ago that emulators can support Vulkan. so you can try to fix this problem by turning your computer off and on again. additionally, be aware that the SDKs and gradles are downloaded. you can reach especially gradles with this step: